# JAXB Unmarshal an unwrapped list of Objects

Tags: java, xml, list, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have to parse XML in Java objects and the XML contains an unwrapped list of objects that looks like :

```
<main>
    <mainPropA>Main Property A</mainPropA>
    <mainPropB>Main Property B</mainPropB>
    <elements>
        <propA>Property A1</propA>
        <propB>Property B1</propB>
        <propA>Property A2</propA>
        <propB>Property B2</propB>
        ...
    </elements>
</main>
```

So in this case I have Java code that should look like :

```
public class MainClass {
    private String mainPropA;
    private String mainPropB;
    private List<Element> elements;
}

public class Element {
    private String propA;
    private String propB;
}
```

I can not figure out how to map this.

I tried the following mapping and can get the first Element to populate in the list, but not the others.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "main")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MainClass {
    private String mainPropA;
    private String mainPropB;
    @XmlElement(name = "elements")
    private List<Element> elements;
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Element {
    private String propA;
    private String propB;
}
```

I've tried various combinations of annotations, but the annotations above has gotten me the closest to seeing something other than null.

Is there a way to get this to work?

I can't change the XML that is coming to me, so that is out.

I'm using JAXB, but am not tied to it in any way.   Also using Java 7, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    @XmlRootElement(name = "main")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class MainClass {
        @XmlElement(name = "mainPropA")
        private String title;
        @XmlElement(name = "mainPropB")
        private String author;
        private Elements elements;

        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        static class Elements {
            List<String> propA;
            List<String> propB;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm..   tried this and it works with my sample XML.   I'd have to create some helper methods to pull out an object made from list elements (Element 1 is made up of propA.get(0) and propB.get(0)), but that is doable.   My concern is when I have an unbalanced element properties.   So I have <elements><propA>property 1a</propA><propA>property 2a</propA><propB>property 2b</propB></elements>.   The first element doesn't have a property B, so the 2nd element would have it's propB as the first in the list.   I don't know how to get around this.

Comment: This works as long as I have an even number of properties, so am marking this as the answer.   If the third party comes back and says that they don't guarantee that each property will always be there, then something else will have to be done.